# Why does the Software Keyboard cause Widget Rebuilds on Open/Close?

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, textfield

I have a screen, which contains a `Form` with a `StreamBuilder`. when I load initial data from `StreamBuilder`, `TextFormField` show data as expected.
When I tap inside the `TextFormField`, the software keyboard shows up, which causes the widgets to rebuild. The same happens again when the keyboard goes down again.

Unfortunately, the `StreamBuilder` is subscribed again and the text box values is replaced with the initial value.

Here is my code:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: _bloc.inputObservable(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return TextFormField(
          // ...
        );
      }
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this? I'm getting the same behavior using a TabBarView.

Comment: no. did you face the similar , please add the solution here when you found, it will help to others.

Comment: Please describe behavior what you want to achieve and show code of you bloc. I'll help you.

Comment: did you add a key to the textformfield. The reason why the screen gets rebuild could be because you added a key to the textformfield which causes the keyboard to close

Comment: @Roshan does [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65963713/6509751) answer your question? :)

Answer (score 36):

### Keyboard causing rebuilds

It makes **total sense** and **is expected** that the software keyboard opening *causes rebuilds*. Behind the scenes, the `MediaQuery` is [updated with **view insets**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/viewInsets.html). These `MediaQueryData.viewInsets` make sure that your UI knows about the keyboard obscuring it. Abstractly, the keyboard obscuring a screen causes a change to the window and most of the time to your UI, which requires changes to the UI - a rebuild.

I can make the confident guess that you are using a [`Scaffold`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html) in your Flutter application. Like many other framework widgets, the `Scaffold` widgets **depends** (see [`InheritedWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html)) on the [`MediaQuery`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) (that gets its data from the [`Window`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/BindingBase/window.html) containing your app) using `MediaQuery.of(context)`.
See [`MediaQueryData`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData-class.html) for more information.

---

It all boils down to the `Scaffold` having a dependency on the view insets. This allows it to **resize** when these **view insets** change. Basically, when the keyboard is opened, the view insets update, which allows the scaffold to shrink at the bottom, removing the *obscured* space.

Long story short, the scaffold adapting to the adjusted view insets requires the scaffold UI to rebuild. And since your widgets are necessarily children of the scaffold (likely the `body`), your widgets are also rebuilt when that happens.

You can *disable* the view insets resizing behavior using [`Scaffold.resizeToAvoidBottomInset`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPageScaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomInset.html). However, this will not necessarily stop the rebuilds as there might still be a dependency on the `MediaQuery`. I will explain how you should really think about the problem in the following.

#### Idempotent build methods

You should always build your Flutter widgets in a way where your `build` methods are **idempotent**.
The paradigm is that a build call could happen *at any point in time*, up to 60 times per second (or more if on a higher refresh rate).

What I mean by *idempotent build calls* is that when nothing about your widget configuration (in the case of [`StatelessWidget`s](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html)) or nothing about your state (in the case of [`StatefulWidget`s](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)) changes, the resulting widget tree should be **strictly the same**. Thus, you do not want to handle *any* state in `build` - its only responsibility should be representing the current configuration or state.

---

The software keyboard opening causing rebuilds is simply a good example for why this is so. Other examples are rotating the device, resizing on web, but it can really be anything as your widget tree starts to get complex (more on that below).

### `StreamBuilder` resubscribing on rebuild

To come back to the original question: in this case, your problem is that you are approaching the `StreamBuilder` incorrectly. You should **not** feed it a stream that is **recreated** each build.

The way stream builders work is by subscribing to the initial stream and then resubscribing *whenever the stream is updated*. This means that when the `stream` property of the `StreamBuilder` widget is different between two `build` calls, the stream builder will unsubscribe from the first and subscribe to the second (new) stream.

You can see this in the [`_StreamBuilderBaseState.didUpdateWidget` implementation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/b21e08c80160e89c800543a4b9990459bc71043d/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/async.dart#L114):

```dart
if (oldWidget.stream != widget.stream) {
  if (_subscription != null) {
    _unsubscribe();
    _summary = widget.afterDisconnected(_summary);
  }
  _subscribe();
}
```

The obvious solution here is that you will want to supply the **same stream** between different build calls when you do not want to resubscribe. This goes back to *idempotent build calls*!

---

A `StreamController` for example will always return the same stream, which means that it is safe to use `stream: streamController.stream` in your `StreamBuilder`. Basically, all controller, behavior subject, etc. implementations should behave this way - as long as you are not **recreating** your stream, `StreamBuilder` will properly take care of it!

The faulty function in your case is therefore `_bloc.inputObservable()`, which creates a new stream each time instead of returning the same one.

#### Notes

Note that I said that build calls can happen "at any point in time". In reality, you *can* (technically) control exactly when every build happens in your app. However, a normal app will be so complex that you cannot possibly have control over that, hence, you will want to have idempotent build calls.
The keyboard causing rebuilds is a good example for this.

If you think about it on a high level, this is exactly what you want - the framework and its widget (or widgets that you create) take care of responding to outside changes and rebuilding whenever necessary. Your leaf widgets in the tree should not care about whether a rebuild happens - they should be fine being placed in any environment and the framework takes care of reacting to changes to that environment by rebuilding correspondently.

I hope that I was able to clear this up for you :)

Comment: Your answer was really helpful, even though most beginners like me are after the code and less with the details.  You did a great explanation :)

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is a piece of gold!

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue in my application. What resolved my issue was to make my "widget tree clean" as suggested by one of the programmers on this forum.

Try moving the definition of your stream to init state. This will prevent your stream from disconnecting and reconnecting every time there is a rebuild.

```
var datastream;

@override
  void initState() {
    dataStream = _bloc.inputObservable();
    super.initState();
  }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: dataStream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return TextFormField(
          // ...
        );
      }
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be resolved by creating a stateful widget like following

```
class StatefulWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onInit;
  final Widget child;
  const StatefulWrapper({@required this.onInit, @required this.child});
  @override
  _StatefulWrapperState createState() => _StatefulWrapperState();
}

class _StatefulWrapperState extends State<StatefulWrapper> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    if (widget.onInit.call != null) {
      widget.onInit();
    }

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }
}
```

and wrapping the stateless widget using the wrapper

```
Widget body;

class WidgetStateless extends StatelessWidget {

  WidgetStateless();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StatefulWrapper(
      onInit: () async {
      //Create the body widget in the onInit
      body = Container();
      },
      child : body
    )
  }
```